# MobX - Run constructor of one store in another?

Tags: javascript, mobx

So I have 2 stores, an `AuthorStore`:

```
class AuthorStore {
  constructor() {
      // has author.name and is always present in storage
      AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(action((data) => {
        this.author = JSON.parse(data);
      }));
  }

  @observable author = null;
}
```

and a `BookStore`:

```
import AuthorStore from 'authorStore';
class BookStore {
  @observable book = {
    authorName: AuthorStore.author.name,
    bookTitle: null
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error in `BookStore` that it cannot get property of `null`, as if the `AuthorStore.author.name` is null. So it's reading the default `author` value from the `AuthorStore` without the constructor running first to assign it the value.

How can I get the value assigned by the `AuthorStore` constructor to `author` in the `BookStore`?

Comment: The constructor is probably running as intended in your `AuthStore`, but the operation is asynchronous, which may result in that `AuthorStore.author` and consequently `AuthorStore.author.name` has no value yet when you construct your `BookStore`. Also, when you write `AuthorStore.author.name` you are dereferencing the value. [Primitives are not observable in that manner](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/pitfalls.html#dereference-values-as-lately-as-possible), so it's best to store a reference to just the `AuthorStore.author` until you need it.

Comment: hmm... I understand what you mean about the value being returned as `null` because of the constructor's asynchronous operation, but I am still not sure how to get the value into `BookStore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store a reference to the `getItem('author')`-promise, and make sure it is fulfilled before you do anything in the bookstore:

```
// authorStore.js
class AuthorStore {
  @observable author = null;
  getAuthorPromise = null;

  constructor() {
    this.getAuthorPromise = AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(action((data) => {
      this.author = JSON.parse(data);
    }));
  }
}

export default new AuthorStore();

// bookStore.js
class BookStore {
  @observable book = null;

  constructor() {
    authorStore.getAuthorPromise.then(action(() => 
      this.book = {
        authorName: authorStore.author.name,
        bookTitle: null
      };
    ));
  }
}
```

You could also get the author before you create any stores and give the author to the `AuthorStore` constructor, so you can create your `BookStore` synchronously:

```
// AuthorStore.js
class AuthorStore {
  @observable author = null;

  constructor(author) {
    this.author = author;
  }
}

export default AuthorStore;

// BookStore.js
class BookStore {
  @observable book = null;
  authorStore = null;

  constructor(authorStore) {
    this.authorStore = authorStore;
    this.book = {
      authorName: authorStore.author.name,
      bookTitle: null
    };
  }
}

export default BookStore;

// app.js
import AuthorStore from './AuthorStore';
import BookStore from './BookStore';

AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(data => {
  const author = JSON.parse(data);
  const authorStore = new AuthorStore(author);
  const bookStore = new BookStore(authorStore);
}));
```

Keep in mind that there are a lot of ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks Tholle for the help :) I think your second statement of getting the author before creating any stores would probably be the cleanest option, and then give it to the `AuthorStore` constructor so I can create `BookStore` synchronously. What would that look like? I am trying locally but I am getting the `cannot read property name of null`

Comment: @Wonka Updated the answer with one way to do it :)

Comment: Thanks again Tholle!

Comment: @Wonka No problem :) Would be interesting if the real MobX pros came with their solutions also.

Comment: Yup - me too. Would be nice to see @mwestsrate's solution :)

Comment: @Wonka Michel wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@mweststrate/how-to-decouple-state-and-ui-a-k-a-you-dont-need-componentwillmount-cc90b787aa37#.881vsig5c) yesterday, which gives a very nice alternative with `fromPromise`.

Comment: Thanks Tholle, I just read it and attempted it but couldn't get it to work with `fromPromise`. Opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39103568/485961