# MobX - Observable value promised in a store constructor using fromPromise stays null when accessed in another store?

Tags: mobx

So I have 2 stores, an `AuthorStore`:

```
class AuthorStore {
  constructor() {
      // has author.name and is always present in storage
      AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(action((data) => {
        this.author = JSON.parse(data);
      }));
  }

  @observable author = null;
}
```

and a `BookStore`:

```
import AuthorStore from 'authorStore';
class BookStore {
  @observable book = {
    authorName: AuthorStore.author.name,
    bookTitle: null
  }
}
```

I keep getting an error in `BookStore` that it cannot get property of `null`, as if the `AuthorStore.author.name` is null. So it's reading the default `author` value from the `AuthorStore` without the constructor running first to assign it the value.

I came across the new `mobx-utils` `fromPromise` which I think would get the `author` value if it exists in local storage, and wait for `AsyncStorage`  to assign it to the `author` observable, so it can be called from another store without being `null`.

I tried using `fromPromise` first in the `AuthorStore` to log the `author` value, but it shows as Got `undefined` in console, and the usual `null` error in the `BookStore` when it comes to the `AuthorStore.author` part.

**UPDATE:**

```
class AuthorStore {
  @observable author = null;

  @computed get theAuthor() {
    authorPromise = fromPromise(AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(data => JSON.parse(data)));

    // combine with when..
    when(
      () => authorPromise.state !== "pending",
      () => {
        console.log("Got Author", authorPromise.reason || authorPromise.value) // This runs, and returns author
        console.log("Got Name", authorPromise.reason || authorPromise.value.name) // This runs, and returns name
        return authorPromise.value; // This doesn't get returned in BookStore when calling this computed
      }
    );
  }
}

class BookStore {
  @observable book = {
    authorName: AuthorStore.theAuthor.name, // doesn't get computed returned value from promise
    bookTitle: null
  }
}
```

How can I get the `fromPromise` value assigned by the `AuthorStore` computed function `theAuthor` to return the promised `authorPromise` value into `BookStore` under `authorName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FromPromise creates a new object wrapping the original promise. So your `authorFromStorage` is just a normal promise in your example, not having a `state` property at all. So you should change your code to:

`authorPromise = fromPromise(AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(data => JSON.parse(data)))`

And then `when(() => authorPromise.state !== "pending")` etc..

** UPDATE **

```
class AuthorStore {
  @observable author = null;

  constructor() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('author').then(data => { this.author = JSON.parse(data) });
  }
}

class BookStore {
  @observable book = {
    authorName: function() {  // a function in an observable creates a computed prop
      return AuthorStore.author && AuthorStore.author.name
    },
    bookTitle: null
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I updated the last block of code above to reflect your suggestion but I am still getting `null` for some reason. (I tried with `.then(action`, and also with `.then(data` directly, but it is still `null` Not sure why!

Comment: Okay, so started over and I am able to output the author `name` within the `when`'s second console log, so I am able to access it within the `AuthorStore`, but I still can't seem to be able to access the object/name from the `BookStore`

Comment: That is because you just copy the value at the time of creation, which is at that point in time `null`. Probably you mean a function or computed value that returns the author from the AuthorStore

Comment: Sorry mob boss :) But can you show me what you mean?

Comment: `  @observable book = {
    authorName: AuthorStore.author.name,
    bookTitle: null
  }` is just a one-time assignment of the current value of author.name to `authorName`. At that point in time the name is `null` (promise not yet resolved), so that will be authorname. There is no reactive relationship set up here, just a value being copied around. For a little background: https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/best/react.html

Comment: Thanks michel, I read it over. I created a computed under the update in my question, hoping it would wait for the promise in the computed to return the author to the BookStore, so we can access the values, like `AuthorStore.theAuthor.name` But it's still null.. I think we both understand the issue completely at this point, but not sure how to resolve it still..

Comment: added a solution to my answer. Your computed was not computing / returning anything, I meant that you need a computed in the book, so that the authorName can be computed from the current state of the AuthorStore. I hope my updated example makes sense :)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that a function in an observable creates a computed prop. Thank you michel, works great :)